# Get a new array with the difference of each values of an array between 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array

```
[4, 4.5, 1, 1.2, 3, 4.2, 10, 1.5, 9, 9.2, 8.9]
```

I want to be able to create a new containing every element in this array within a distance of 1.

I.E, the new array that will be gotten from the above will be:

```
[4, 4.2, 4.5], [1, 1.2, 1.5], [8.9, 9, 9.2].
```

I attempted to solve the problem with below

```js
function arrayTogether(arrays) {
  let filters = [];
  let totalArrays = [];
  let n = arrays.length;

  function your_callback(a, b) {
    if (a - b <= 1) return true;
    return false;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let ok = true;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if ((j != i) && !(your_callback(arrays[i], arrays[j]))) {
        ok = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (ok) {
      filters.push(arrays[i]);
    }
  }

  console.dir(filters);
  console.dir(totalArrays);
}

arrayTogether([4, 4.5, 1, 1.2, 3, 4.2, 10, 1.5, 9, 9.2, 8.9]);
```

But I only get an array of `[1, 1.2, 1.5]`, please how do I get an actual array containing a combining of arrays of the requirements.

Comment: You've added `totalArrays`. For what reason? And why don't you use it (change its content)?

Comment: Can there ever be overlap? For example, what if `3.2` was in the original array? Would it be listed with the first group?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do totalArrays.push(filters) but didn't get what I wanted, can you show me how to go about getting my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do it like this:

- sort array in ascending order
- use reduce, to iterate over array and find "groups" of numbers within 1.0 of each other
- each time the number is within 1.0, push it to the inner array (keep extending the "group"), each time it is not, push a new inner array to the outer array with that item in position 0.

Any questions, let me know:

```js
function arrayTogether(initArray) {
  
  const [first, ...sortedArr] = initArray.sort((a,b) => a - b)
  
  const groupedArr = sortedArr.reduce((aggArr, item) => {
    const lastIndex = aggArr.length - 1;
    const lowerLimit = aggArr[lastIndex][0];
    
    if (item - lowerLimit <= 1.0){
      aggArr[lastIndex].push(item);
    }
    else {
      aggArr.push([item]);
    }
    
    return aggArr;
    
  }, [[first]]);
  
  return groupedArr;
  
}

console.log(arrayTogether([4, 4.5, 1, 1.2, 3, 4.2, 10, 1.5, 9, 9.2, 8.9]));
```

Output:

```js
[
  [    1,      1.2,    1.5  ],
  [    3,      4    ],
  [    4.2,    4.5  ],
  [    8.9,    9,      9.2  ],
  [    10  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important you can first sort the data and then check if the difference between current and last inserted element is larger then 1.

```js
const data = [4, 4.5, 1, 1.2, 3, 4.2, 10, 1.5, 9, 9.2, 8.9]

function group(data, dist = 1) {
  const copy = [...data].sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return copy.reduce((r, e) => {
    let lastArr = r[r.length - 1] || [];
    let lastEl = lastArr[lastArr.length - 1]
    if (!lastEl || Math.abs(lastEl - e) > dist) {
      r.push([e])
    } else {
      lastArr.push(e)
    }

    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = group(data);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Sort the numbers
2) Use `forEach` loop, and maintain the `temp` array to push the elements when ever the difference is 1.
3) When difference is more, then just push the temp array to output and reset the temp array.
4) Make `diff` as second argument that way you can reuse if required.

```js
const data = [4, 4.5, 1, 1.2, 3, 4.2, 10, 1.5, 9, 9.2, 8.9];

const split = (data, diff = 1) => {
  const output = [];
  let temp = [];
  data
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .forEach(num => {
      const [first] = temp;
      if (first && num > first + diff) {
        output.push([...temp]);
        temp = [];
      }
      temp.push(num);
    });
  if (temp.length > 0) {
    output.push([...temp]);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(split(data));
console.log(split(data, 2));
```